# how to add css when creating new page in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I created new page in CMS blocks > pages . but I need to add new classes "css" to the new page , how can I manage this from Magneto , also If I want to add new users who access the Magneto and how can I give them permissions to access some menus as Catalog , system ...etc and they didn't access others how can I do it.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest and most efficient way to add styles to one specific CMS page only is to use the Layout Update XML input area in the Design tab of that page.  I've included a screenshot below that shows you what I mean, in that case it's adding in some JS.

[image: Magento - add styles / js to one specific CMS page]

For you to add CSS you'd just create your CSS file and upload it to your active theme's CSS directory.  You'd use the following code in your Layout Update XML input area;

```
<reference name="head">
   <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/pagestyles.css</stylesheet></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Sorry, missed that bit - that really is a totally separate and unrelated question.  You should split them into two questions and repost that part.